# Cannot use distinct w/ a different Order by using Django ORM

Tags: django

I have seen a few posts that reference this issue on Stackoverflow, but I cannot figure out how to get the business need solved, if the query changes.

I am trying to get the last 10 contacts that have sent a message to the organization

```
messages = (Message.objects.order_by('-created_at').distinct('contact_id'))
```

However, I get this error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("messages"."contact_id") "messages"."id"...
```

I see that the distinct column must match the order by column, but a distinct created_at, isn't what the business needs to solve the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you please share your model ?

Comment: to use `distinct` with `contact_id` you have to set `order_by` in this order `order_by('contact_id','-created_at')`

Comment: The query does return like this, but the order is based on contact rather than created at

Answer (score 0):

The field in `distinct()` **must** be included and **must** be the first one in `order_by()`, in your case `contact_id`:

```
Message.objects.order_by('contact_id', '-created_at').distinct('contact_id')
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct